# sys_get_temp_dir() - returns C:\Windows on windows8

Tags: php, windows-8

On windows8 I got this with php 5.3:

```
echo sys_get_temp_dir();
```

output:

```
C:\Windows
```

Am I not understand something or it is a bug?

***UPD***

trying `$_ENV`:

```
<?php

var_export($_ENV);
```

output:

```
array ( )
```

Checking `upload_tmp_dir`:

```
<?php

echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
```

output:

```
C:\Windows\Temp
```

Comment: may be it is a bug with `windows8`. Try to update your `php` version and check again.

Comment: This does not happen on Win. 7, so it might be a Win. 8 issue.

Comment: Reported earlier today: [Bug #64410 sys_get_temp_dir() returns incorrect path](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64410), no answer yet from the PHP team.

Comment: yes, it was me who reported. But Im still unsure how I can find a workaround for this

Comment: try to print `$_ENV['TMP']`, `$_ENV['TMPDIR']`, and `$_ENV['TEMP']`

Comment: I've confirmed the php bug 64410, one of the devs wanted feedback whether this is still occuring, in my case it is php 5.4.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the PHP source, it will call [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine the temp directory. According to the documentation, the windows directory C:\Windows is the last fallthrough option. You should check under which user profile PHP or its host process is running, maybe the environment needs some fixing.

Comment: everything is standard in my setup.. Apache 2.2 as a web service + php 5.3 with mod_fcgid as fcgi module. Cant find anything wrong in my php.ini.

Comment: you should re-check whether TMP and/or TEMP environment variables are set correctly on your system. If Apache runs as a Windows service, it is likely that the %USERPROFILE% temp dir isn't available, leaving only these two. Have you tried running a simple test-script from command line under your own user account that just outputs the value of sys_get_temp_dir() ?

Comment: also keep in mind this article when changing environment variables: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821761

Comment: Hm.. you were right about the console script: c:\Program Files (x86)\PHP>php -r "echo sys_get_temp_dir();"
C:\Users\Vitaly\AppData\Local\Temp

Answer (score 1):

Related to this [PHP Bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64410) (only CGI context?).

I have the same problem and the solution is to change the apache configuration to expose the *TEMP* system environment variable to PHP with [this directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#passenv) in apache configuration file (httpd.conf) :

```
PassEnv TEMP
```

Don't forget to activate the *env_module*, generally uncomment the line "LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so".

This solution fixes the result of these PHP functions: *sys_get_temp_dir()*, *tempnam()*.